# Mongodb failing to handle multiple saves in short amount of time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas, node-cron

I have a nodejs-cron based application that sends automated scheduled requests in order to update some fields in a mongodb document (I am using mongodb atlas).

My application are sending over 200 requests within a 15-20 minutes time lapse, and only 40%-70% of these requests success to update the document.

For example, I have 200 objects in my document and I need to add a property in each of them : `{foo : bar}`. In my case, Only 40%-70% (Depending on mongoDb mood) will be successfully added to the document's objects.

I checked with my app and the requests are well executed, so the problem is at the mongodb atlas level.

I've tried to use `save()` as well as `updateOne({obj: [.... {foo: "bar"}]})` but same problem in both cases.

Do you have any suggestion for me ?